# TFS: Failed to create directory '\\Ms-devtest\Files\SHP'. User 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' needs write permissions to the path

Tags: tfs

I am trying to run my first build in TFS 2010 but a have a permissions error. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path `\\Ms-devtest\Files\SHP` is to access a network share. But the inbuilt system accounts (including 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM') have no rights beyond the host machine.

Either move to use a local folder, or use a domain account with access to the share.

Answer (score 2):

Create the mentioned Shared Folder and give the NETWORK SERVICE (this is the credential where the build service is running with) write permissions on the share.

You can also check this MSDN library on how to setup the Drop Folders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394.aspx